# dbt to handle the same query multiple if-else conditions

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dbt

One of my very first `dbt` questions as I am also new to this framework.

I have the following query, and have a question what's the best approach to write this better?

I used `var('partner')` and with `uuid` to use for `status` column, and also the temp table name `'points_{{partner}}'`

Question :

1. What's the best way to structure and organize this to handle said 20+ partners instead of having a duplicate of the same query on 20 SQL files?  I am using `'points_{{partner}}'` here, but ultimately I want to have many of these partner specific views store in the destination.
2. Can I just put `partner` in the `schema.yml` or other dbt files, that I can just load and reference it? Any example on how to do this?  In this way, I was thinking about not needing to have multiple `if-else` statements with 20+ partners to handle, and instead it is just simply `{{partner}}`

```
WITH 'points_{{partner}}' AS (
  SELECT
    TO_CHAR(
      TO_DATE(points_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
      'YYYY-MM'
    ) AS "months",
    SUM(points_amount) AS "points_amount",
    CASE
    {% if var('partner') == 'nike' %}
      WHEN uuid = '00000000-d64b-46ea-8454-428279b15064' THEN 'OK'
      WHEN uuid = '11111111-dc9a-493a-b1c0-6a798a4889ac' THEN 'NOT_OK'
    {% elif var('partner') == 'puma' %}
      WHEN uuid = '22222222-9644-4c6f-bcb6-57ae8401dfc0' THEN 'OK'
      WHEN uuid = '33333333-af79-4364-8b26-c8106627c937' THEN 'NOT_OK'
    {% endif %}
    END AS "status"
  FROM
    dbt.raw_points
  WHERE
    {% if var('partner') == 'nike' %}
      partner_uuid = '88888888-cfd3-47f4-b6da-447401aefbae'
    {% elif var('partner') == 'puma' %}
      partner_uuid = '99999999-f345-43e8-a335-a1268969095e'
    {% endif %}
  GROUP BY
    months,
    points_amount,
    status
  ORDER BY
    months DESC
)

SELECT * FROM 'points_{{partner}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are doing an single cte that templates all partners into that single object.
Another alternative would be a template cte that union each partner together.

(This example assumes that you have each `raw_points` table within a unique schema per partner - a soft single tenancy model for the warehouse)

Example:

```
{% set partners = get_column_values(table=ref('my_distinct_partners'), 
       column='partner_name', max_records=50, filter_column='partner_status', filter_value='OK') %}

{% if partners != '' %}

with partner_group_points as (

    {% for partner in partners %}    

        SELECT
            TO_CHAR( TO_DATE(points_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM') AS "months",
            '{{partner}}' as partner,
            SUM(points_amount) AS "points_amount",
            <custom calculation for status here> as status
        FROM 
            `{{ target.project }}.platform_data_{{partner}}.raw_points`
        GROUP BY
            months,
            points_amount,
            status
        ORDER BY months DESC
        {% if not loop.last %} UNION ALL {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
)    

SELECT 
months,
partner,
sum(points_amount) as points_amount,
status
FROM partner_group_points
GROUP BY months,partner,status

{% endif %}
```

I'm completely making this up since I don't know your exact source data but you probably get the gist.